# Error installing nextcloud with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I want to install nextcloud using the official image from the docker hub.

https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/

I tried installing apache on 'Running this image with docker-compose' and copied that piece of code to yaml.

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test1234
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test1234
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

Running that file with the docker-compose up -d command results in an error.

```
ERROR: create _nextcloud: "_nextcloud" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only a-za-z0-9 a-za-z0-9_.- are allowed
```

I think this is a problem because the part I put in the volume is blank and I get this error when I delete the part and run it.

```
ERROR: Named volume "db:/var/lib/mysql:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section
```

In other posts, it is said that you should specify the absolute path, but it does not seem to me.

Is this how i run it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your folder where the compose is located has name `_nextcloud`. The name of folder is prepended to all the global resources created by compose (like volumes or networks). So docker wants to create volume `_nextcloud_nextcloud` it's not possible to create volumes starting with underscore character as message indicates. Change the folder name and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. The error seems to be fixed, but this time I get another error.

Comment: I got this error as well since I am running docker in Windows and my docker-compose file was in D: (root) and that created this issue. I moved the file to a directory in the root and it worked fine.